# Need to display a stacked style bar graph divided into left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I'm writing a small web app to manage a competition on tipping sports teams to win.

On the dashboard I want to display a small graph for each game in a given week showing the preference of team selection for users - I want it to look something like this:

Team 1  ----xxx | xxxx--- Team 2

Where the x's represent a bar the size of the percentage of tips. As the games are listed, all of the centre bars should be lined up.

I've seen this before but can't remember where - and not knowing what the type of graph / chart is makes it hard to find - been Googling for a good few hours.

If anyone could point me to a js / jQuery library or plugin that can render these kinds of graphs, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Cheers,
Ryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't look to a plugin to do this. Write something yourself! Create some markup to display your graph, and have two divs that represent your sides. Then use some JS to adjust their widths. Here's an example that I whipped up. http://cdpn.io/ivjhw . You'll see in the JS that you can adjust the totals of the left and right sides, and the graph will reflect them.

Comment: Thanks! I've taken your suggestion and decided to just do it myself.
I assumed that someone, somewhere would have already written something like this.